# Problems using fread() on input stream from text file converted from dos to unix format

Tags: c, io

I'm just trying to read in some data using C, but I'm having trouble getting fread to do what it's supposed to do.  I think it has to do with the format of the data file... It was a DOS file that I changed to Unix format using dos2unix.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    char* temp = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
    while(fread(temp, sizeof(char), 4, in)){
        *(temp + 4) = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        ...
    }
```

The data file looks like this:

```
KAAA
KAAF
KAAO
KAAS
KAAT
KABE
KABI
KABQ
...
```

Output:

```
KAAA^@

KAA^@
F
KA^@
AO
K^@
AAS
^@
KAAT^@

KAB^@
E
KA^@
```

...nonsense

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: For starters, you're not reading the newline.

Comment: ...yup.  that'll do it.  thx man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading only 4 chars, forgetting to account for the new line character. Read 5 characters at a time and it should fix it.

```
char* temp = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
while(fread(temp, sizeof(char), 5, in)){
    *(temp + 4) = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't consume the (one or two) newline character that denotes the end of the line. On Unix, try adding

```
fgetc(in);
```

on Windows,

```
fgetc(in);
fgetc(in);
```

after the call to `fread()`.